# Can I include tooltips in the d3pie rcharts implementation?

Tags: r, d3.js, pie-chart, rcharts

I am creating a d3pie graph with rcharts following [this article](http://timelyportfolio.github.io/rChartsExtra/d3pie/).

I am able to create the pie chart and now I would like to add a tooltip similar to [this one](http://d3pie.org/website/examples/tooltips_placeholders.html).

My code so far is:

```
require(magrittr)
require(dplyr)
require(rCharts)

df<-data.frame(label=c("group1","group2","group3"),value=c(1,5,4),
stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
pie1<-rCharts$new()
pie1$setLib("http://timelyportfolio.github.io/rChartsExtra/d3pie")
pie1$params$chartspec <- list(header = list(title = list(text = "Title"),
                                        subtitle = list(text = "Subtitle")),
                              data = list(content = df),
                              labels = list(lines = list(style = "straight")),
                              tooltips=list(enabled=TRUE,type= "placeholder",
                                            string="{label}"))
pie1
```

I am not sure if including the tooltips is possible with `rcharts`. 
If it is possible my guess is that the problem comes from the `enabled=TRUE`. I also tried: `enabled="[true]"`, `enabled="{true}"` and `enabled=T`. None of them seem to work.

I am starting to learn `d3.js`, however, I want to embed the chart in `rmarkdown` so I would prefer a solution based on R.